# Concept TS check ignores private access modifier

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I want to write a concept Indexable meaning that a sequence either has begin/end that return RandomAccessIterator, or operator[] is defined and returns a value of non void type.

I used ideas from [Stroustrup's article](http://www.stroustrup.com/good_concepts.pdf) for the Sequence concept and augmented it with:

```
template <class T>
concept bool Indexable = Sequence<T> || requires(T t, size_t n) {
    { t[n] } -> NotVoid;
};
```

It works on most cases but fails on the following:

```
struct Bad {
    std::vector<int> nums;

private:
    int& operator[](size_t ind) {
        return nums[ind];
    }
};

static_assert(!Indexable<Bad>, "fail");
```

For some reason my concept ignores the fact that operator[] is defined private and returns true. What am I missing?

Comment: Out of interest, how would you *use* your `Indexable` concept in practice? Since it doesn’t guarantee a uniform interface the code using it would still need to statically dispatch on the existence of either `begin(x)[i]` or `x[i]`.

Comment: It is an academic assignment without any practical applications.

Comment: Seems not intended: "Access checking is done as part of the substitution process" https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#deduct-8.note-1

Comment: What compiler are you using? GCC trunk seems to work fine https://godbolt.org/z/hY6UvY The `static_assert` passes for private `operator[]` and fails for public.

Comment: `concept bool` indicates that you are compiling against the Concepts TS, not C++20 concepts. The rules between the two might be different.

Comment: g++ (Ubuntu 9.2.1-28ubuntu1) 9.2.1 20200203 with -fconcepts flag

Comment: @magom001: gcc 9.x has only TS ( from gcc 6 on). C++20 concepts are in gcc 10!

Answer (score 1):

This is GCC bug [#67225 "Expression constraint with a constrained result turns off access checking"](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67225), which will be fixed in GCC10.